# Reactjs: how to merge front end website and admin panel in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am new in reactjs and I've created a front end website using html template. Now I want to merge it with admin pane, I've downloaded html template and tried to combine with Front end website. But admin's css are clashing with front end's css files.

Is there any other way to achieve this or any suggestion regarding it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For local css import, you can check out `css modules` library: https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules

Comment: ok if I use this, will it conflict within other css which are defined in index.html?